# Homomorphic image of the modular group that has the infinite order.

Tags: group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $G$ be a group generated by $A$ and $B$ such that $A^2=B^3=1$ and $AB$ has infinite order. It seems that $G$ should be equal to the modular group $C_2\ast C_3$. Is it true? If yes, how to show this?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Also, your title doesn't seem to match the body of the question.

Comment: Definitions are important here. How are you defining the free product?

Comment: The free product $C_2\star C_3$ is a group that has the following presentation $$\langle \alpha ,\beta | \alpha^2=1, \beta^3=1\rangle.$$ By definition $G$ defined in the question is a homomorphic image of $C_2\star C_3$. What I am asking is wether there is any aother realtion between $A$ and $B$ out of $A^2=B^3=1$ providing that $AB$ has infinite order.

Comment: In other words, my questin may be stated as follows: Let  the homomorphism be given by $\Phi(\alpha)=A$, $\Phi(\beta)=B$. Obviously $\Phi$ is a surjection. Is it a injection as well?

Comment: Is there any reason to expect that $AB$ has finite order in the group $\langle A,B\mid A^2,B^3,ABA^{-1}=B^2\rangle$?

Comment: Yes, @DavidSheard; that's a presentation for $D_3$.

Comment: @artur If you want to avoid the question being closed, then please don't respond to queries in comments - edit the question.

Answer (score 3):

I shouldn't really be answering this, because the question is missing context, but it  is not true.

For example $ab$ has infinite order in the group $\langle a,b \mid a^2=b^3 = [a,b]^3=1 \rangle$.